# Using \ref{} in listing

Tags: cross-referencing, listings, align

what I'm trying to do is making an equation like this

```
\begin{align}
    a^2+b^2=c^2 \label{equation}
\end{align}
```

and then putting `\ref{equation}` into my source code, so that when I do

```
\lstinputlisting[language=Python]{source_code.py}
```

the number of the referenced equation appears in the listing.

P.S. I don't need to also have a hyperlink to the equation, but it sure wouldn't hurt :-)

Comment: Then you'll have to escape to latex somewhere inside that python code, see `escapeinside` in the listings manual

Answer (score 3):

Now for everyone:

You have to define special comment delimeters, like this

```
\lstset{escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}}
```

Now everything in your Code, that comes between `(*@` and `@*)` is used as LaTeX-Code. You can use this for labels to refer to a line or even for my problem.